# JOIN/Union Two tables, removing NULL where possible (similar to pandas concatenate)

Tags: sql-server, join, null, union, merge

I am wondering how to perform an operation that I guess is most akin to a concatenate if you're familiar with pandas.

Basically, what I want to do seems like a UNION where records are "collapsed" in a sense to remove NULL values (where say, the ID and DATE are the same). I've tried a UNION, FULL JOIN, and SELF JOIN but none of those seem to produce the desired result. It seems like maybe MSSQL's MERGE is maybe what I'm looking for? It seems like that operation is meant for table creation, however.

My end goal is basically to create a view from the result. All I really need is the SELECT statement that allows me to do further manipulation.

To help visualize the problem, let's say I have the below tables:

```
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+
| ID | Date   | FloorRating | CeilingRating |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 1A | 1/1/18 | 9           | 6             |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 1A | 1/1/19 | 9           | 7             |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 3D | 2/2/19 | 5           | 8             |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+
| 3D | 3/3/19 | 4           | 9             |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+


+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| ID | Date   | WindowRating | FanRating |
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 1A | 1/1/18 | 4            | 7         |
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 1A | 2/2/19 | 3            | 7         |
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 3D | 2/2/19 | 9            | 4         |
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
| 3D | 8/8/19 | 1            | 3         |
+----+--------+--------------+-----------+
```

What I want to end up with is something like this, where all possible ID-Date combinations are accounted for and field values are filled in where possible:

```
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| ID | Date   | FloorRating | CeilingRating | WindowRating | FanRating |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1A | 1/1/18 | 9           | 6             | 4            | 7         |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1A | 1/1/19 | 9           | 7             |              |           |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1A | 2/2/19 |             |               | 3            | 7         |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| 3D | 2/2/19 | 5           | 8             | 9            | 4         |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| 3D | 3/3/19 | 4           | 9             |              |           |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| 3D | 8/8/19 |             |               | 1            | 3         |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I appreciate any help or tips you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried a UNION, FULL JOIN, and SELF JOIN but none of those seem to
>   produce the desired result

`FULL JOIN` works fine. Maybe you were joining on the wrong predicate or didn't coalesce the results from the `ID` and `Date` columns (done with `ISNULL` below)?

[db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e778e67d88facab3cad3dacb35f07f47)

```
SELECT ISNULL(T1.[ID], T2.[ID]) AS [ID],
       ISNULL(T1.Date, T2.Date) AS Date,
       [FloorRating],
       [CeilingRating],
       [WindowRating],
       [FanRating]
FROM   Table1 T1
       FULL JOIN Table2 T2
              ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
                 AND T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
ORDER  BY [ID],
          Date
```